# Nexus кэш и борьба с ним

Tags: jenkins, непрерывная-интеграция, nexus

Столкнулся с такой проблемой.

С помощью Jenkins билдим артефакт - тут все без проблем, дальше нам нужно его выгрузить на Nexus

Далее на Nexus  удаляю старый артефакт :

```
curl -u {user}:{password} -X DELETE https://path.repos/repos/new/filename.zip
```

И выгружаю новый артефакт

```
curl -u {user}:{password} --upload-file filename.zip https://path.repos/repos/new/filename.zip
```

Но имеется следующая проблема, после успешной выгрузки на нексус - запускаю следующий степ с деплоем - который тянет этот самый артефакт - и вот тут возникает проблема, что скачивается тот АРТЕФАКТ который был до удаления (может даже несколько раз удалять)
т.е. есть какой то кеш - который используется первоочередно.

Пробовал сделать

```
curl -u {user}:{password} -X DELETE --silent https://path.repos/repos/new/filename.zip
```

Так же не помогло... 
Как можно от этого избавиться ? 
 - Под капот нексусу лезть нельзя;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Получилось побороть эту проблему, не совсем правильно как я думаю, но пока что работает :

При билде имеем следующую структуру на Nexus

art-name:
|- 2020-05
|-- file1
|-- file2
|- latest 
|-- FileLatest

ВОт собственно при билде я удаляю папку latest и перезаписываю